# Can't get javascript to work on my website; Django Polls

Tags: javascript, django

For an assessment at UNI i need to make a webpage list the contents of an object dynamically. Sorry I am very new to this and need to complete this assessment.

The code below is what I need to change to get the website to display the contents of an object below the link when it is clicked, as of now, when i click the link nothing happens.

I have probably explained this very wrong. The assessment is based on the Django webpage tutorials.

Please ask me to explain further if required, as I don't really understand how to explain my issue. The attached image is what the outcome needs to be..

```
    {%load staticfiles%}

<script src="(% static "polls/jquery-3.3.1.js" %)"></script>


{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul id="question-list">
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li id=" {{ question.id }}"><a href="#">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        <ul style="display: none">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}


<script>
$(document).ready(function()    (
    $("#question-list li").click(fuction(){

        var question_id = string($(this).attr('id'));
        var detail.id = "#detail-" + question_id;

        if ($(detail_id).is("visible"))    {
        $(detail_id).hide();
        }
        else {

            var url = "/polls/" + question_id + "/";

            $.getJSON(url, function(data)    {

                $.each(data, function(i, details) {
                    $(detail_id + " li").text(details);
                    $(detail_id).show();

                });
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

[Image that the response needs to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raeKh.png)

Comment: where is the attached image? also check the console for the errors

Comment: Hey, I just added the image to the original post, also there are not console errors

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is happening because when you see the (a) tag href which is gives the address of the question is set to #.

Which means nothing will happen even when you click it.

Just change the href to the corresponding element tag. 
I need to see the views to tell the exact tag it would be something like question.tag

Update -

Replace this `<a href="#">' by '<a href="{{ question.detail }}">`

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replies. These are the views:   def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

##def detail(request, question_id):
   #question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
   #return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def detail(request, question_id):
   return JsonResponse({"detail": "You're looking at question %s" %question_id})

Comment: I am not too sure as to what i need to change the views to though? also, i apologize for the poor formatting, I am very new to this site

Comment: If you could provide help that would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: Wait what do you want after clicking the question?

Comment: When I click the question I need to have the contents of the question to be listed below, I provided an example in the original post.

Comment: I also don't understand why the {{question.id}} is not greyed out?

Comment: Replace this <a href="#"> by <a href="{{ question.detail }}">

Comment: Thank you very much! One last thing, what do I need to change in the views to have the image display this correctly?

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if it fixed the problem :)

Comment: I just tried the changes you suggested but the webpage still does nothing when it is clicked?

Comment: Instead of question.detail use detail only and let me know

Comment: I get this as a response : Not Found: /polls/(% static
[22/Oct/2018 23:32:46] "GET /polls/(%%20static HTTP/1.1" 404 2743

Comment: Do you have dummy question in your database?

Comment: Yes, there is a question with multiple choices added

Comment: Why is your detail view is commented out?

Comment: There is a second detail view below that one, the commented out one is the one I had to use when the link went to a new webpage